# Can an imported module use modules already imported?

Tags: python, module, python-import, exec, turtle-graphics

edit:
since no one understands the question I will rewrite it.

file1

```py
import turtle
import file2

turtle.uselesscode()

turtle.mainloop()
```

file2

```py
turtle.goto(-50,-50)
turtle.fd(50)
#more code with the turtle module
```

questions:

1. why am I getting an error when importing file2 (code runs):

> NameError: name 'Turtle' is not defined

(module "file2" isn't able to use turtle imported in "file1")

2. can i use exec() instead of importing module "file2", and will I be able to without putting `from turtle import *` inside file2

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer... see [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. How do you know your code doesn't work? Be explicit, and [edit] the question.

Comment: thank you. I don't know if those are rhetorical questions, but I will insert the error message, I just can't at the moment

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question/problem/use case, but regardless, avoid `*` imports completely--they pollute the namespace and are considered bad practice. Especially in turtle, there's over 120 functions that are dumped into the global namespace when you import `from turtle import *`, leading to all manner of confusion between instance mode and functional mode, as well as name clashes. Just use `from turtle import Screen, Turtle` and create an instance of the turtle, avoiding a number of footguns. The code will be more readable since you'll know which module functions belong to.

Comment: I don't know where the `exec()` is in your code, but you never need this function.

Comment: @ggorlen it isn't here, basically I thought I would use ```exec()``` instead of importing. I didn't know before import runs all code of the module(if there is no if "__name__" = "__main__"). Also about the from .. import 
I know it isn't good but this is not a really advanced project I'm working on so I don't really need a lot more modules.

Comment: question is rewritten so you can take a look if you want to

Comment: I see, thanks. You might want to update your error `NameError: name 'Turtle' is not defined` to match. Can you just `import turtle` in file2 as well as file1? That's normally how you use libraries. I guess I don't understand why there's a need to not use the library import in both files.

Answer (score 0):

**Title question:**
If I understand your question correctly, the answer is Yes, but it is not necessary to import the module if you are not going to use it since if module X uses module Y, module Y is already being imported internally by module X.

If you want, you can see it yourself by checking the code for module X and seeing how in the code it uses "Import" to import module Y

**Description question:**
Regarding the exec() function, it is a function that executes python code passed in string format, there is also eval() which has a similar behavior but it does not execute, you will not be able to create variables but you will be able to see the content.

Comment: Which module is X and which Y in the last example?

Comment: I think I had not understood your question correctly, but it should be noted that exec() executes the string in your same environment so that it can execute any function that you have imported.

Comment: question is rewritten so you can take a look if you want to